# Regex Match Pattern in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Hey I have the following strings as input:

```
"abcol"  
"ab_col"  
"cold"  
"col_ab"  
"col.ab"
```

I have the string col to search from. I'm using regex to match

```
Match matchResults = Regex.Match(input , "col", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I want to match only the string that has this pattern 
`[Any special character or nothing ] + col + [Any special character or nothing]`

From the above inputs, I want to return only 
`ab_col, col_ab , col.ab`

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

[Any special character] = [^A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: What defines a "special character"?

Comment: Not an alpha numeric character [^A-Za-z0-9] (anything that's not an alphabet or number)

Comment: You have not specified what you have tried, and neither are you asking a proper question, but rather saying "solve this for me". I understand that this can be tricky to get right, but this question could probably be solved if you searched around the Internet before asking.

Comment: Using [^A-Za-z0-9] I was able to get partially what I want. I'm familiar with Regex and I tried searching the internet. I know I have to use the "|" but not sure exactly how. That's why I posted here. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex: -

```
(?:^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]|^)col(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9].*$|$)
```

**Explanation : -**

```
(?:   // non-capturing
  ^   // match at start of the string
  .*[^a-zA-Z0-9]  // match anything followed by a non-alphanumeric before `col`
    |     // or
  ^       // match the start itself (means nothing before col)
)
  col  // match col
(?:   // non-capturing
  [^a-zA-Z0-9].*  // match a non-alphanumeric after `col` followed by anything
   $     // match end of string
   |     // or
   $     // just match the end itself (nothing after col)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`@"(^|.*[\W_])col([\W_].*|$)"` this is your pattern. `\w` is alphanumeric character and `\W` is non alphanumeric character. `^` means line start and `$` means line end. `|` is the or. so `(^|.*\W)` means line start or some characters and non alphanumeric after them.

**EDIT:**

yes, underline is alphanumeric too... so you should write `[\W_]` (non alphanumeric or underline) instead of `\W`

Comment: This will not satisfy the requirement that "ab_col" be a match or "col_ab", because '_' is included in the '\w' class.

Comment: Just ran your edit again, still fails. It will match "ab.col", but not "ab_col". Its due to the use of the '\W' class which says "don't match '_'"

Comment: \W skips underscores as well which I don't want

Comment: @user1178492 - If you group it (which is what I added when I edited the answer) so that instead of \W you have [\W_] it will match the underscore. I like this one over [^a-zA-Z-0-9] just because it is more compact, but some may find the full listing more readable in the long run.