# Replace substring which comes in middle of string only

Tags: c#, regex

I want regx pattern in C# which find substring in any string which comes in middle only. Let say ,

```
Input : "toprohitpop rohittoppop toppoprohit"
```

find substring : `"rohit"`

Replace with : `"$$$$"`

Output : `"top$$$$pop rohittoppop toppoprohit"`

if substring "rohit" comes in left or right of the string then it should not be replaced.Substring "rohit" will only be replaced when it comes in middle of string .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: "in the middle of string" - your example makes it seem like you're looking for when it's in the middle of a **word**. So which is it? Like, say, if you're replacing `foo` with `BAR`, would the input `foo foo foo` result in `foo BAR foo` or `foo foo foo`?

Comment: @HamZa To be fair since the answer to this is a oneliner, I'm not sure what an "attempted solution" would be. Boilerplate call to `Regex.Replace` that we can safely assume?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690372/regex-match-pattern-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690372/regex-match-pattern-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @millimoose: something like "I tried *this* but it gave me *that*" would probably calm down tensions.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? it doesn't show research effort at all

Answer (score 4):

Use non-word-break anchors:

```
\Brohit\B
```

The `\B` will only match if it is in the middle of a word.

[Read about it.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: /\Brohit\B/.test('aarohitaaaaaaaaaa'). does he means middle symetric ? if not , they you're right

Comment: @RoyiNamir I assumed not, because in this kind of problem, the middle of the string usually means anything but the start and end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "toprohitpop rohittoppop toppoprohit";
var regex = new Regex(@"\Brohit\B");
var output = regex.Replace(input, "$$$$$$$$");
```

See "Anchors" in [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Also, be careful with the '$' in the substitution string (see comments)

Comment: You need "$$$$$$$$" since `$$` is equal to `$` literal

Answer (score -2):

Use the following regex: `.+rohit.+`

Basically it enforeces at least one char before rohit and one after

Comment: Then the entire string will be replaced.